# Python values out of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list which looks like this:

```
[(0.2, 'Item1'),(0.25,'Item2'),(0.23,'Item3')]
```

I want a list that looks like this out of it.

```
['Item1','Item2','Item3']
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension is all you need:

```
[t[1] for t in inputlist]
```

which selects every second item. Alternatively, map the list (Python 3 returns an iterator here, so beware):

```
from operator import itemgetter

map(itemgetter(1), inputlist)
```

or you can pick the *last* element of each tuple with `-1`:

```
[t[-1] for t in inputlist]
```

or you could use tuple assignment:

```
[item for ratio, item in inputlist]
```

or you could go really obscure and use `zip()` to transpose the columns and rows:

```
zip(*inputlist)[-1]
```

although the latter returns a tuple instead of a list.

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = [(0.2, 'Item1'), (0.25, 'Item2'), (0.23, 'Item3')]
>>> [t[1] for t in inputlist]
['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(1), inputlist)
['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
>>> [t[-1] for t in inputlist]
['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
>>> [item for ratio, item in inputlist]
['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
>>> zip(*inputlist)[-1]
('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import operator
map(operator.itemgetter(-1), your_list)
```

Demo:

```
>>> items = [(0.2, 'Item1'),(0,25,'Item2'),(0.23,'Item3')]
>>> import operator
>>> map(operator.itemgetter(-1), items)
['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
```

Another option would be a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x[-1] for x in items]
['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
```

In case you meant `(0.25, 'Item2')` instead of `(0, 25, 'Item2')` you can also use `1` (second element) instead of `-1` (last element) in the subscript/itemgetter.

Comment: Beware: `map()` is a generator in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension should be fine:

```
>>> [item for (num, item) in yourlist]
['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = [(0.2, 'Item1'), (0.25, 'Item2'), (0.23, 'Item3')]
>>> [x[1] for x in lst]
['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
>>> [x for _,x in lst] # alternately
['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items = [(0.2, 'Item1'), (0.25, 'Item2'), (0.23, 'Item3')]
print(dict(items).values())

['Item2', 'Item3', 'Item1']
```

And if order of items are needs:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

items = [(0.2, 'Item1'), (0.25, 'Item2'), (0.23, 'Item3')]
print(OrderedDict(items).values())

['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
```